# Modify res without mutating argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, eslint

I am writing an Express application that I'm linting using the [AirBnB eslint configuration](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). That lint configuration provides a `no-params-reassign` check, which flags reassignment of parameters and members of those parameters as errors. I personally like this, but I am unsure if there's a way to modify `req` and `res` in Express without mutating the function parameters.

For example, I want to rewrite part of the request in a middleware:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.url = req.url.replace("regex", "replacement");
});
```

This sets off a lint error. I know I can make the error go away by doing this:

```
app.use((_req, res, next) => {
  req = _req;
  req.url = req.url.replace("regex", "replacement");
});
```

... but that seems like a kinda dumb solution. Is there a means of replacing the `req` and `res` variables for future middleware invocations in Express, or is the only way to persist changes to actually mutate them?

I know I can just override the `no-params-reassign` rule, but I wanted to see if it's possible for me to achieve this without doing so. Thanks!

Comment: Short answer? Yeah, the general rule is to mutate `req` and `res` as they go by your middleware. The official guide even suggests [doing it that way](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html). There may be a way around it, but I've never seen one. Does `req.replacedUrl = req.url.replace("regex", "replacement");` make an `eslint` warning?

Comment: Yeah—the dogma is to not mutate the parameters. Guess Express may be incompatible with that?

Comment: I could definitely be mistaken, but it seems to be the recommended way to do it with Express. And most nodejs http / server libraries, truth be told. I think the idea is that middleware is typically used to "extend" the request / response objects with the pieces you need. For better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a means of replacing the req and res variables for future middleware invocations in Express:

Use the `app` object as persistent storage at the first invocation, then check it on subsequent invocations

```
app.use( (req, res, next) => { 
  app.req = app.req || req;
  app.req.url = app.req.url.replace("regex", "replacement");
});
```

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` can be used to avoid mutation:

```
app.use( (req, res, next) => { 
  app.req = app.req || JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req));
  app.req.url = app.req.url.replace("regex", "replacement");
});
```

**References**

- [ES6 class / instance properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545495/)
- [JavaScript: How to pass object by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/)
- [JSON.parse and JSON.stringify are not idempotent and that is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629456/)
- [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/)